# send null parameter from Ajax to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a jquery function that makes an AJAX call to a function in controller.
the controller function accepts 3 arguments. 
At certain times I need to pass 3rd parameter as null.. since that will be used to make a check in the controller function.

Here's how I am calling the function when I need to send value of 3rd parameter.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/Transactions/Cancel/" + transactionID + "/" + reasonForCancel,
            data: $.toJSON(Comment),
            success: function (cancelInfo) {

                }

        });
```

now for the same call in other place I don't have "comment" value(the one that I m sending in Comment object) and hence I need to pass null there. 
Please suggest me what to do here.

P.S. I can't test the functionality when null has to be sent so that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Please post more code surrounding this, including the controller.

Comment: if you do not have a comment value, then you might use comment = 'null'; just to make sure you pass some value even if you dont have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
var myObj = null;
if(objectIsNotNull){
   myObj = $.toJSON(Comment);
}
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/Transactions/Cancel/" + transactionID + "/" + reasonForCancel,
    data: myObj,
    success: function (cancelInfo) {
     }

});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    var param1 = val1;
    var param2 = val2;
    var param3 = null;
    var paramComment = '';
    var param = { "p1": "", "p2": "", "p3": "", "comment" : "" };
    param.p1= param1;
    param.p2= param2;
    param.p3 = param3;
    param.comment = paramComment;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Transactions/Cancel',
        data: JSON.stringify(param),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (cancelInfo) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.